# Automatically refreshing a UILabel with the current date and time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an application that has a `UILabel` displaying the current date and time, obtained from an instance of `NSDate`.

I'd like the `UILabel` to update every second with the current date and time.

How would I update this automatically, rather than just with the initial value obtained during `viewDidLoad`?

Would I need to have a method that updates this and call it every second using some sort of timer or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you search through Apple's references using the keyword `timer`? If not, try again and look closely at `NSTimer`.

Comment: Timers looks like the way to go!

Comment: I know I can try using an NSTimer, but I'm wondering if this is the "best" way of doing it or if there is a better way.

Comment: I agree that even a single sentence like, "I looked into NSTimer, but couldn't make heads or tails of it", would have been a good addition to the question.  I think the SO faq suggests that questions should include info about what was tried so far.  That seems right to me, but I don't agree that a person must "earn" an answer by first proving that they banged their head against something for hours or days (which I've seen expressed on SO in the past).

Comment: danh: You're entirely right, I should have said that I was aware of NSTimer but wanted to know if it was the "correct way" of doing things before diving in and writing some code that would only end up being chucked away. My bad with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method, and use the `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` to call that method as a selector every second.